# Writing numbers in reverse c++

Tags: c++, string, reverse

I tried to write numbers in reverse and actually I found a way without converting them in string but my code works only for below 10000000000.
I don't know why I even changed int to long long but still doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>



using namespace std;


/*
 * 
*/
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
long long n;
scanf("%lld",&n);
printf("%lld",n%10);
for (int i=10;i<n;) {
    i=10*i;
    printf("%lld",((n%i)-(n%(i/10)))/(i/10));
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This isn't even modern C++, this is C.

Comment: I don't think your code works even for input less than 10000000000.  Try inputting 10 or 100.

Comment: yes you are right i didnt notice it until now thx losif code looks way better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   long long n;

   scanf("%lld",&n);
   printf("%lld",n%10);

   while (n /= 10) {
       printf("%lld",n%10);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: operator/ for basic data types (just like most, if not all, operators for basic types) returns the strongest type of its two operands. (excerpt from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780578/c-type-of-the-division)

Answer (score 2):

There is a neater version as shown by Iosif. However, if you are interested in **why** it's not working, I think it's because you need to declare `i` as `long long` as well.