# Dividing by a negative number in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to divide by negative numbers where both the quotient and divisor are negative. However it returns 0 when done like this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
double m = -46 / -120;
cout << m << endl;
}
```

output: 0

Comment: `-46 / -120;` uses integer division. You'd get `0` with positives values as well. You want `-46.0 / -120.0`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ -- type of the division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780578/c-type-of-the-division)

Answer (score 2):

As pointed in the comment, it is true that your instance of code will produce 0 even for a Positive number.
So it should be like this:

```
#include<iostream>

int main() {
   double m = -46.0 / -120.0;
   std::cout << m << '\n';
}
```